# jQuery replace image source in IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, replace

In the DOM I am loading a static Google Map image.
When the document is ready with jQuery sometimes I need to replace that image with a bigger version.
Problem is that in IE the CPU goes whooooooo because IE is still looking to load the initial image with no success.
Is there a way to cancel or clear the previous load?

EDIT: I should note that I use .html() inside a function when SWFObject is not successfully embedded..

I am not able to reproduce the problem in following example, but basically I use this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img#myImage").html('<img id="myImage" src="images/002.jpg" />');
});
```

HTML

```
<img id="myImage" src="images/001.jpg" />
```

Comment: Why are you using load? You are not replacing the contents of a HTML node, and the browser automatically starts loading when src is changed.

Comment: Hmmm, is the load actually necessary in that case, since it should be firing on dom ready, and thus perhaps before the images get loaded anyway?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in my example, no .load(), I use .html()

Comment: On a side note: is there a reason why you cannot just have the image with a blank src attribute in the markup and load either the bigger or smaller one in `$(document).ready()` ?
This way, you will not have unnecessary downloads.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion andras but I want to load an image when the user has javascript disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.html()` function replaces the HTML *inside* the `img` tag. Of course, there is no HTML in the `img` tag. Instead, use `.attr()`:

```
$("img#myImage").attr('src', 'images/002.jpg');
```

Calling this immediately changes the source of the image and the browser should begin loading the new image.